# AG-Grid render Bootstrap-Select as a dropdwon

Tags: ag-grid, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have implemented editable AG-Grid. In the grid, one of the column displays country of the player as shown below:

[image]

Now in last column, when user click on the cell, I want to display list of available countries as a dropdown.

Here by default AG-Grid displays normal dropdown. Which I want to replace with Bootstrap-select.

To achieve this, I have implemented custom selector and using [Bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) library.

But when cell is clicked, Dropdown is not being rendered. I am not getting any error though in console.

Here is the code of my custom cell-editor:

```
var selectCellEdior = function () { };
selectCellEdior.prototype = {
    init: function (params) {

        selector = document.createElement('select');

        for(var i = 0; i < params.values.length; i++) {
          var option = params.values[i];
          $('<option />', { value: option, text: option }).appendTo(selector);
        }

        this.cellSelector = selector;

        $(this.cellSelector).selectpicker({ size: 'auto' });


    },
    getValue: function () {
        return $(this.cellSelector).find('.btn-text').text();
    },
    getGui: function () {
        return this.cellSelector;
    },
    destroy: function () {
        $(this.cellSelector).remove();
    }
};
```

Here is the [**Sample Code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cazt8M8eggPZk4uxDB8s?p=preview)

I dont understand what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `selectpicker` jQuery method seems to add a `display: none` to the select element. Ag-Grid is adding it to the DOM you just can't see it. Additionally the `getValue` function is not returning the selected option's text.

The following changes to `getValue` and `getGui` will make the grid work:

```
  ...
  getValue: function () {
    return $(this.cellSelector).val();
  },
  getGui: function () {
    this.cellSelector.style.display = 'block';
    return this.cellSelector;
  },
  ...
```

[Here is the modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/W5t1FV4faN5XeB7rC9lw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this now.... Ag-grid has a method afterGuiAttached that is called after the GUI has been attached to the Grid's cell. If you're noticing that the bootstrap-select still isn't "quite right" after following the instructions above, put ALL of the calls to selectpicker in afterGuiAttached instead of init or getGui. This will place the bootstrap-select into a div with the right classes it needs (dropdown, bootstrap-select, etc), and create all of the bootstrap-select elements that are properly shown/hidden.